# residue theorem in complex analysis(Rudin)

Tags: complex-analysis

In P.224, Rudin's real and complex analsysis,
I doubt an equation (3).

The full statement containing equation (3) is following :

> > If $\Gamma$ is a cycle and a $\notin$ $\Gamma$*, then $Q(z)=\sum_1^m c_k (z-a)^{-k}$ implies that $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}Q(z)\, \mathrm dz  =  Res(f;a)  Ind_{\Gamma}(a),$$
> >     where $Ind_{\Gamma}(a)$ is the index of $a$ w.r.t. $\Gamma$, defined by $Ind_{\Gamma}(a)$=$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}\frac{dz}{z-a}$.

In this statement, I thought that the author used the Cauchy's theorem(Theorem 10.35).
However, $Q(z)$ is not holomorphic at $a$ and futhermore, $Res(f;a) \neq Q(a)$.

How can the equation (3) hold??

Please explain the reason explicitly.

Comment: This looks like Cauchy's Residue Theorem almost exactly. Is $Q(z)$ defined as only the negative terms of the power series for $f(z)$?

Comment: @Silynn  Yeah. Rudin defiend Q as the principal part of f at a

Comment: Then yeah, this is Cauchy's Residue Theorem for a single pole inside the curve. The requirement is that $Q(z)$ be holomorphic at all but a finite number of points inside the curve, so being not holomorphic at $a$ is fine. You can prove it pretty easily by using $\oint_\Gamma z^ndz=0$ if $n\neq -1$

Comment: @Silynn Nono I does not mean that. In my question, I think that Q (z) behave f(z)/(z-a) in the Cauchy theorem(thm10.35). Then it follows that Q (a) is the residue of f at a, consequently. But I don't understand this part because Q does not have its value at a unless Q(z)=c/(z-a)

Comment: $Q(z)$ and $f(z)$ have the same residue at $a$, ($c_{-1}$), if you integrate over a closed curve, $\oint_\Gamma z^ndz=0$ if $n\neq -1$, so the only piece that remains is $\oint_\Gamma c_{-1}z^{-1}dz=c_{-1}\cdot 2\pi i=2\pi i\cdot Res(f;a)$

Comment: @Silynn oh... I forgot the fact about integral of $z^n$. You are correct. Now I understand completely. Thanks a lot.